# with nHibernate, what happends when you want to return an object that doesn't map to a table/entity?

Tags: nhibernate

With nHibernate, what happends when you want to return an object that doesn't map to a table/entity?

Comment: I'm not understanding something.  Hibernate only knows about persistent objects.  If there's no relationship between a table and the entity, it's not persistent.  How can Hibernate know about it?  Sounds like it's just an object that you'd obtain from a constructor or factory.  Hibernate isn't involved.

Comment: But wouldn't I be using HQL or something to query for the object?

Comment: This has been answered so many times already... if you provide more about what you're trying to do, we might be able to help you more. However, the basic answer is that NHibernate querying is object-oriented and it only knows about what has been mapped. It'd be like trying to call a method on a class that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's based off of data in the database, but not necessarily your business entities, you can use a projection.

http://japikse.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-projections-and-transformers-in.html
http://elegantcode.com/2007/10/30/nhibernate-projections/

Comment: To clarify this answer, you can project aggregate values based off of mapped properties, but you can't arbitrarily select unmapped columns without dropping back to SQL.